# docker exec -it my-container /bin/bash doesn't get me to the shell in Powershell ISE console

Tags: powershell, docker

Running this command in PS allows me to enter in the Shell of the container (based on Linux) but the same command in the Powershell ISE console seems to wait for ever... are not they using the same PS environment?
thanks

Comment: well, they are not exactly the same thing, so theres no big surprise, tbh

Answer (score 0):

Applications which require console input are not supported in the ISE.

here's a [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/02/04/console-application-non-support-in-the-ise/)

This isn't a docker thing, it's about how the console in the ISE is written.

Comment: It's a real pity there is no full integration ... Powershell_ISE could be very useful tool. But... again another "..they'll almost get it..." :-(  Anyway, many thanks for the quick responses.